# Correcting term to variance OU process when using Euler Maruyama and time step of 1

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to simulate the following OU process.

$$
dX_t = -\theta X_t dt + \sigma dW_t
$$

I then simulated the process using the Eulers-Maruyama discretization approach i.e

$$
X_{t+\Delta t} = X_{t} -\theta X_t \Delta t + \sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}\epsilon
$$

where $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$

Because I want to simulate hourly data and my parameters have already been calibrated at that same frequency I've assumed that $\Delta t = 1$

I've been doing some tests to ensure that the variance of the simulations matches the closed-form solution for the variance and that it also converges to its long-term variance
$$\frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}(1-e^{-2\theta (T-t)})$$

What I've noticed is that the variance tends to be overestimated the larger the value of $\Delta t$. I think this is due to the fact that compared to the actual solution for $X_T = X_te^{-\theta (T-t)} + \int^T_t\sigma e^{-\theta(T-s)} dW_s$ the Euler-Maruyama is a first-order approximation.

It is easy to see that if we do a first-order approximation of the first term after the equal sign

$$
X_te^{-\theta \Delta t} \approx X_t(1-\theta \Delta t)
$$

Something that I've noticed is that the difference between the variance of the simulations when I use $\Delta t = 1$ and the true variance of the process is proportional. Heuristically I've found that I can get the simulated variance to match the true variance from the process if I multiply the standard deviation of the Euler-Maruyama process by the scalar

$$e^{-\frac{1}{4} \theta \Delta t}$$

and

$$
X_{t+\Delta t} = X_{t} -\theta X_t \Delta t + \sigma e^{-\frac{1}{4} \theta \Delta t} \sqrt{\Delta t}\epsilon
$$

I have used different values of $\sigma$ and $\theta$ to test that it is the adjustment holds when $\Delta t = 1$ however I've been unable to prove mathematically why this is the correct adjustment term.

Has anyone come across this before? I would love to find a way to explain this formally

Comment: Could you add what magnitude $σ$ and $θ$ have? It makes a difference with this fixed step size if their magnitude is $1$ or $0.01$. Do you get better results if you apply the exponential integrating factor first to the SDE and then apply Euler-Maruyama?

Comment: And please use the correct discretization. Ito SDE only work in one time direction, it should be $$X_{t+ \Delta t} = X_{t} -\theta X_t \Delta t + \sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}\epsilon.$$

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann I've made the correction. I guess that you are mentioning in your first response is using Doob's method and simulating $X_{t+\Delta t}=X_te^{-\theta \Delta t} + \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{2 \theta}(1-e^{-2\theta \Delta t})}\epsilon$?
I've tested values of $\sigma$ from 0.05 to 10. For $\theta$ values close to 0 up to 0.2 seem to be working. The higher $\theta$ the worst is the approximation. Do you have any insight I can use?

Comment: It's still an Euler-type method. While the modifications catch some error sources, enough others remain and become prominent at larger sizes of the product $θΔt$.

Comment: Thanks @Lutz Lehmann I was wondering if you had a sense as to how the measure the error and correct the variance term as a function of $\theta \Delta t$